# Trouble constructing dynamic SOQL using LIKE expression - not getting results

Tags: visualforce, soql

```
String soql = 'SELECT name, student_id__c, qualification__c, email__c ' +
    'FROM name__c WHERE name LIKE :' +
    String.escapeSingleQuotes(studentName)+'%';
List<Name__c> records = Database.query(soql);
```

When I try to execute this query with a `studentName` of `'John Doe'`, I get a `QueryException`:

> System.QueryException: unexpected token: 'Doe'

Comment: What is the problem ? Do you have any error message ? Your question is not clear !

Comment: What is the error that you are getting?

Answer (score 2):

Might be this useful for you.

```
Soql =  'Select id,name from student__c where name LIKE \'%' +String.escapeSingleQuotes(studentName) + '%\' ';
```

If i am wrong then correct me.

Comment: Its my pleasure @VenkataSravanKumarBandari